# AJAX https to http $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, session-variables

I've seen articles discussing this, but I haven't seen an answer on how to get around it or a good suggestion for an alternative.

I have a total AJAX site including authentication.  When a user signs up or logs in, they make a cross domain https to my site which they initially load http.  Obviously, I need them to be able to set some session variables in https and access them in http.

I know you "can't" do this, but can you?  If absolutely not, what's the most secure alternative?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like there is an answer for you here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414786/javascript-cross-domain-call-call-from-http-to-https