# Youtube API in IE9 and lower

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm using the Youtube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=en ), in particular: playlists, playlistItems and channels to load.

This works great in all browsers,e xpect IE9 and lower. Here I always get a `"No Transport"` error.

This is a simple sample code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Youtube API Test</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <code>    
    </code>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('code').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $('code').text(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Note I remove the parameters, in Chrome and FF this returns a youtube error, in IE a "No Transport" error).

I tried using the `xdomain` plugin (https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain)

and the `XDomainRequest` plugin (https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest#instructions)

as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied?answertab=oldest#tab-top), with no success. Anything I am missing, does this work for anybody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you can't make ajax call from an **http** Site to an **https** Service!! Esle all examples I found fail:

> 7. Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page
>
> This restriction means that if your AJAX page is at
>   http://example.com, then your target URL must also begin with HTTP.
>   Similarly, if your AJAX page is at https://example.com, then your
>   target URL must also begin with HTTPS.
>
> It was definitely our intent to prevent HTTPS pages from making
>   XDomainRequests for HTTP-based resources, as that scenario presents a
>   Mixed Content Security Threat which many developers and most users do
>   not understand.
>
> However, this restriction is overly broad, because it prevents HTTP
>   pages from issuing XDomainRequests targeted to HTTPS pages. While it’s
>   true that the HTTP page itself may have been compromised, there’s no
>   reason that it should be forbidden from receiving public resources
>   securely.
>
> Worst of all, the Same Scheme restriction means that web developers
>   testing their pages locally using the file:// scheme will find that
>   all of the XDomainRequests are blocked because file:// doesn’t match
>   either http:// or https://, which are the only valid target schemes
>   (point #1). To workaround this issue, web developers must host their
>   pages on a local web server (e.g. IIS, the Visual Studio hosting
>   server, etc).

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

HTTPS with Visual Studio's built-in ASP.NET Development Server: [HTTPS with Visual Studio's built-in ASP.NET Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113/https-with-visual-studios-built-in-asp-net-development-server)

Related on SO: [JavaScript cross-domain call: call from HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414786/javascript-cross-domain-call-call-from-http-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the gapi client library, which will auto-discover the youtube api descriptions and provide a wrapper around the REST interface..

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/

That client library states support for IE8+, and has some smart code integrated to get around browser limitations..