# Console error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to fetch the outputed text from a website. If the website displays `true` for a user having a certain assetid, it will display the userid. If the website displays `false`, it will skip that user and move to the next.

I'm using the following code to process the instructions listed above:

```
var countedOwners = 0, nameOfOwner;
document.writeln("<h1>Found owners</h1>");

var setUp = function() { var assetID = prompt("Enter asset ID in the input box which you would like to search for","1285307");

if (assetID != null && assetID.length > 5 && assetID.length < 10 && !isNaN(assetID)) {

var speed = prompt("How fast would you like to scan in milliseconds? - Do not type under 200 milliseconds for overload issues.");

if (speed != null) {

if (speed > 200) {
var userID = prompt("What ID would you like to start from(will increase by 1 every time)) Default: 1", "1");
if (userID != null && !isNaN(userID)) {
itemScanner(assetID, speed, userID);
}

} else {

itemScanner();

}
}
}};


function createLink(userID, speed) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=" + (userID - 1));
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=" + (userID - 1);
document.body.appendChild(a);
//creating speed increaser...
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");  
var t = document.createTextNode("Increase speed?"); 
btn.appendChild(t);  
document.body.appendChild(btn); 
btn.onclick = function(){ var newSpeed = prompt("Your current speed is " + speed + " milliseconds. \n Input what speed you would like it to run at below.","300")
speed = newSpeed;
};
}

var itemScanner = function(assetID, speed, userID) {
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?userId=" + userID + "&assetId=" + assetID,
type: 'GET',
}).success(function(Data) {
var pageInfo = Data;
if (pageInfo === true) {
$.get("http://api.roblox.com/Users/" + userID, function(json) {
nameOfOwner = json.Username;
countedOwners = countedOwners + 1; 
console.info("Discovered owner of the item, the user's ID is " + userID + "." + "The name is " + nameOfOwner); 
console.info("Concurrent discovered owners - " + countedOwners + ".");
document.write("<h4>Found an Owner ("+ "User ID = " + (userID - 1) + ")" + " Owner Name: " + nameOfOwner + "." + "</h4>");
createLink(userID, speed);
});
}
userID++;
});
}, speed);
}


setUp();
```

However when I run it through the Google Chrome console on Roblox.com, it displays the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?userId=undefined&assetId=undefined.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.roblox.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: this happens because you have an external address where you want to load smth - in your case i think its a problem between www.roblox.com and api.roblox.com. Maybe you need a .htaccess file here

Comment: I didn't think that would be a problem, as api.roblox.com is a subdomain of roblox.com..

Comment: whats the host? is it roblox.com?

Comment: Yes, roblox.com is the host.

Comment: hm, it looks that your host is offline - `503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.[80]` could this be the reason? if i try to visit your page, its online....

Comment: I wasn't aware that the site is offline... I can access it without any issues (meaning it's online) - could there be a typo/error in the script causing this?

Comment: yes. I think its because of your https / http crossdomain. i am searching at the moment how to solve this

Comment: does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414786/javascript-cross-domain-call-call-from-http-to-https

Answer (score 1):

The resource that you're requesting has blocked requests from external domains and it does this by setting out a HTTP header, this header is Access-Control-Allow-Origin, by looking at the error message it appears there is no header setting which means it doesn't have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * which if you're calling from a different domain you will need.

Here's a bit more on CORS [a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

I've assumed you're not in control of the page you're trying to access which could be wrong, another solution could be to add that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.roblox.com  to this web page.

Comment: As I mentioned in a reply to messerbill, api.roblox.com is a subdomain of roblox.com rather than a different domain, therefore I thought it would be exempt from this issue.

Comment: just like i said - i bet its because of the http / https cross-domain - have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414786/javascript-cross-domain-call-call-from-http-to-https

Comment: I don't believe I require https, would it resolve anything if I changed all of them to begin with http?

Comment: Hi Lizzy, that's a bit of a loaded question and will depend on the context.  One thing I will say is I wouldn't recommend mixing secure and unsecure content because it will cause browsers to throw warnings.  I'd pick a delivery mechanism and stick to it but I still don't think this will solve your error.