# sending request from https to http from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello all i am having a strange issue with sending a request from https site to http site by google chrome extension..

> jquery.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip/stats/search.php?keywords=apple'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

this is my code which is injected to the site ...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=q]').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            v = $(this).val();
            v=encodeURI(v);
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myipaddress/stats/search.php?keywords='+v,
        data:{'search':v},
        success: function(data){ 
        //something....
        }   
        });
           }


  }); 
  });
```

Manifest.json

```
   {
  "name": "Ads",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Injecting stuff",

      "background":
         {
         "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
              },
          "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Inject!"
          },
         "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
         "http://*/*",
         "tabs"
        ],"content_scripts" : [
         {
       "js": ["jquery.js", "inject.js"],
           "matches": ["*://*/*"]
      }
       ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a security feature.** Most (all?) modern browsers require HTTPS domains to load all content via HTTPS. Any insecure (HTTP) requests will be blocked.

However, you might want to check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414786/javascript-cross-domain-call-call-from-http-to-https), it has some interesting links that may lead you to a solution.

Comment: the thread did not helped much but still thankyou ... Is there any thing which can solve this issue ..?

Comment: @Lisa Unfortunately, no. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make a request from the content script due to the page's origin, delegate that to the background script.

[Send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background script to instruct it to make a request, then return the response. Remember to `return true` from the handler to indicate that you will respond asynchronously.

Comment: can you provide me some sample code for this ??

Comment: Linked question links to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699615/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-using-background-pages/7699773#7699773) as an example.