# How to query API from within HTTPS encrypted ReactJS page?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, https, gunicorn

In an effort to move a web platform to HTTPS, I ran into a problem. Here is the setup that I am using:

- Python Flask-based http server is served by gunicorn
- Nginx directs SSL-encrypted HTTPS traffic to the http server
- The http server serves a ReactJS page
- Independent Python Flask-based API server is served by gunicorn

Now I am making PUT and GET requests from the ReactJS page into the API server. Because the ReactJS page is proxied via HTTPS, of course any request is fully encrypted. Thus, the API server receives encrypted requests.

My question is, how can I query an API server from within an HTTPS ReactJS page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right question is "how to override browser security that blocks me from sending requests by http:// from within page hosted at https://".

The answer is: no way to do that.

If it is not possible to enable SSL for API server you may use your own server act as secure proxy. So finally it'd look like `ReactJS -> HTTPS -> your server -> HTTP -> API server`

UPD similar case [sending request from https to http from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487784/sending-request-from-https-to-http-from-chrome-extension) (spoiler: no workarounds available)

Comment: Thank you @skyboyer for the fast response. I will try the solution you propose, ie. querying from ReactJS back to my own HTTPS page and submit queries server-side.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution has actually just solved my issue!