# Need a workaround for cross domain ajax post in IE7

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-7, cors

So IE7 does not support CORS (cross origin resource sharing). However, due to nature of my app, I have to make a cross domain ajax post. Is there some way to get this to work in IE7? Unfortunately, I cannot use a server side proxy for security reasons. Perhaps using an iFrame?

I forgot to mention, but I control the other server also.

Comment: It's post not a get. JSONP only supports GET requests right?

Answer (score 2):

The [Easy XDM library](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) was developed to solve the cross origin problem :

> easyXDM is a Javascript library that enables you as a developer to easily work around the limitation set in place by the Same Origin Policy, in turn making it easy to communicate and expose javascript API’s across domain boundaries.

I didn't use it yet, but we might have to try it to solve a Http / HTTPS Ajax call problem...

Hope that helps.

Other threads of interests :

- [Ajax using https on an http page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-http-https-problem)
- [AJAX, Subdomains, and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231478/ajax-subdomains-and-ssl)

Comment: Update from the Easy XDM site - it no longer works w/ IE6 and 7

Comment: Possible solution, as linked on easyXDM website : [How to upgrade](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2011/04/13/microsoft-security-bulletin-ms11-018/)

Answer (score 1):

Do it the old fashioned way: post the form to an iframe using the external domain. You can listen to the onload event on the iframe to know it has completed.

The other option is to use a server-side proxy and post it from there.

Comment: If I use an iFrame, is there a way to communicate between the current document and the iframe?

Comment: No. The Same Origin Policy prevents this. All you get is the onload event for the Iframe itself.

Comment: easyXDM does it by internally using the postMessage API