# Calling BigCommerce API through jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bigcommerce

I am trying to pull products from my BigCommerce store through jQuery Ajax, what I am doing is by passing username and token key:

```
var key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('admin:'+key);
var url = 'https://store-xxxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products.json';
    
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method : 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend : function(req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('done');
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

But every time I get "Failure" message.

Comment: Are you calling from a HTTPS site? `API authentication is handled with HTTP Basic access authentication. Connections to the API must be made with a secure HTTPS connection.` Because code looks fine to me

Comment: i have tried with both ways, but no success, can you clarify it more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231478/ajax-subdomains-and-ssl so I suggest you to call a server side script (on your server) using ajax that will handle those https request to BigCommerce. I'm not 100% if that is the problem.