# IIS/ASP.net set up / configuration to have Safari & IE accept iFrames

Tags: asp.net, security, internet-explorer, iis, iframe

We are researching the IIS/ASP.net set up / configuration to have Safari & IE accept iFrames coming from a secured (Windows 2008 R2) server to another Ubuntu/Nginx secured server.

Everything works smoothly on FF, Chrome and Opera. But the 2 other browsers mentioned earlier are apparently identifying the iFrames as third party content.

(I am suddenly thinking about the fact that a wildcard SSL might have solved this issue? I installed two different ones...)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231478/ajax-subdomains-and-ssl

Comment: It reassures me on the fact that I can have two separate SSLs, which is my case. But in spite of this, I still do not have it running.