# Mixed content error in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ssl, mixed-content

I am having a client side built with angular (ssl enabled) and my server is not ssl enabled. I am getting a mixed content error. I searched for solution online but couldn't find anything that can help me to solve it. I am providing necessary information.

**Component function :**

```
 onSubmit(form:NgForm) {

       this.subscription = this._validation.validation({
            cell_no: form.value.cell_no, pass: form.value.password,
            username: this._common.getConnData().username, password:this._common.getConnData().password
        })
        .subscribe(res => {
             if(typeof res == 'string') // invalid access attempt
             {
                   this.invalid_access = true;
             }
             else // login successful 
             {    
                console.log(res);     
             }
        })
 }
```

**Service function :**

```
validation(data:{})
{
    const body = JSON.stringify(data);
    const headers = new Headers();      
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(this._common.getBaseUrl()+"doctor_panel_api/validation_modified/format/json",
    body, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json()); 
 }
```

I am getting following errors after clicking login button :[image]

The whole app works like a charm if I connect server from my localhost. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you wanna read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231478/ajax-subdomains-and-ssl

Answer (score 2):

It can be due to your client is hosted on https(secure) but making request to http(unsecure).
And your client and server hosted on different servers.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I am looking for a solution. There can be another layer for solving this issue. But I need an optimal solution now. Thanks

Comment: The only solution that is possible is to create proxy server. That will host on the same domain as client and proxy request to real server. By the way its what angular -cli does. Thats why its working on localhost